# Using stored procedure mail to multiple recipients their corresponding records

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, stored-procedures

I am trying to mail the stored procedure records to the corresponding mail ids.
For example, if we have multiple records for the same mail id, then those multiple records should be sent in a single mail. Likewise for different mail ids in the table. This is a preview of my table.

[image: Example]

Comment: So you are running a stored procedure multiple times to get the data per each user of does the stored procedure return all the data for all users? You can use a cursor for this. Run the cursor per each user and inside the cursor get the data for that particular user and execute the db mail.

Comment: I have created stored procedure by combining 2 tables and filtered the output. The records with the same mail id should be sent to the particular mailid(As shown in the above example, 456,245 ids should be sent in a single mail to Sandy@gmail.com and next 123,298 ids should be sent to veda@gmail.com. Likewise..)